# how to get the number of repetitions from List<int>

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
List<int> ListIdProducts = new List<int>();
var IdProductKey = from a in me.ProductKeywords where a.Keyword == item.Id select a;
 foreach (var item2 in IdProductKey)
 {
   ListIdProducts.Add(item2.Product.Value);
 }
```

Result is: 
5
6
7
5
2
5

I need to get the following 5=3, 6=1, 7=1, 2=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var query1 = from a in ListIdProducts 
                         group a by new { a } into g
                         select new
                         {
                             item = g.Key,
                             itemcount = g.Count()
                         };
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) LINQ method:

```
ListIdProducts
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

Answer (score 2):

This a fairly standard group-by problem.

```
//untested
var IdProducts = from a in me.ProductKeywords 
                 where a.Keyword == item.Id 
                 group by a.Product.Value into g
                 select g.Count();
```